# Why Facebook asks me to login?

Tags: firefox, chromium, facebook

I don't have a Facebook account, but I sometimes just browse some publicly available fan pages on Facebook. It was always possible without having to log in. However, for maybe two days, when I try to access them, Facebook asks me to log in.

Tried clearing cookies, turning off uBlock, accessing Facebook from a different browser (even a newly installed one) - still no change. Were there recently any changes on Facebook (that you are aware of) that require everybody to log in, even only to just browse a public fan page?

Or does it happen just for me, but in that case why, and how do they recognize my computer? Did they "restrict" my IP address?

Comment: @Ramhound These are fan pages, not individual profiles. Individual profiles were always impossible to view without login, regardless of privacy setting. And this happens for **every** fanpage I try to view, not only one particular. And for one particular fanpage I know **for certain** (because I know its owners) that nothing has been changed in the settings over the last days.

Comment: @Ramhound If questions about Facebook are out of scope here, where should I ask?